# Import/Export only one table from a database to another [via PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I want to export only one table from my database and then import it to another database via PHP, i tried do this  in phpMyAdmin, i exported from sql-1 in .sql (and gzipped) then imported  to sql-2, but when export is complete it's just show me a blank page. so i want to do this via PHP. i have code for export/import for whole database, but i want import/export only one certain table.

here is my code:

**Import:**

```
<?php
//ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
$mysqlDatabaseName ='db123456789';
$mysqlUserName ='dbo123456789';
$mysqlPassword ='yourPassword';
$mysqlHostName ='db1234.perfora.net';
$mysqlImportFilename ='yourMysqlBackupFile.sql';

//DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
//Export the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysql -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' < ' .$mysqlImportFilename;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
case 0:
echo 'Import file <b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b> successfully imported to database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b>';
break;
case 1:
echo 'There was an error during import. Please make sure the import file is saved in the same folder as this script and check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Import Filename:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b></td></tr></table>';
break;
}
?>
```

**Export:**

```
<?php
//ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
$mysqlDatabaseName ='db123456789';
$mysqlUserName ='dbo123456789';
$mysqlPassword ='myPassword';
$mysqlHostName ='db1234.perfora.net';
$mysqlExportPath ='chooseFilenameForBackup.sql';

//DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
//Export the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysqldump --opt -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' > ~/' .$mysqlExportPath;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
case 0:
echo 'Database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> successfully exported to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
break;
case 1:
echo 'There was a warning during the export of <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
break;
case 2:
echo 'There was an error during export. Please check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr></table>';
break;
}
?>
```

Comment: please read the [manual section of mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html).

Comment: And you've got to _edit below this line_ of your code ...

Comment: i can't figure it out. im not familiar with sql and php.

Comment: That's got not very much to do with sql or php. You're configuring the command line options of mysqldump.  I cite the first line of syntax from the manual: **shell> mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]**

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use MySQL?

CREATE TABLE your_NEW_db_name.your_new_table_name LIKE your_db_name.your_old_table_name;

INSERT your_NEW_db_name.your_new_table_name SELECT * FROM your_db_name.your_old_table_name;

Comment: well, it's just not a simple table, it contains data. i should export then import, i doubt this code will export a table then i can import to new database. let me know if i wrong.

Comment: If both databases are on the same server and are accessable by the same user it should work. Note that you need to point both databases in the query (your_NEW_db_name.your_new_table_name)

Comment: i can't see your_NEW_db_name in your above code (answer) .. it just new_table. after all, i test your code, it got error.

Comment: OK I've edited it... You should replace the example values with your database names and your tables names. If it does not work that way try something else...

Comment: @SamuilBanti You could even do it in one statement (if the requirements you've mentioned are given): `CREATE TABLE your_NEW_db_name.your_new_table_name SELECT * FROM your_db_name.your_old_table_name;`

Comment: MySQL said: #1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'xxxxxx'@'xxxxxx' for table 'td_doing'

Comment: is there another way to do this?

Comment: @ITSolution It seems you have to rely on the export/import via mysqldump. Is it very difficult to add the desired table name to the mysqldump command?

Comment: no, i just wanted to add that table in full. anyway, i solved the problem with a shortcut. i exported whol database, then deleted all table except that one, then exported, then imported to new database. it was dirty work but at least im done. thank you VMai for your help.